# SignalR MSSQL scale

Tags: sql-server, signalr, scalability

Have hard time to get push notifications from server when using MSSQL scalling.
Message flow is one way from server to subscribers (are distributed by groups)
Push messages are not received on UI with the following host configuration:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(new SqlScaleoutConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SignalR"].ConnectionString));
```

Messages are created in SignalRDb and records are present in tables. However they do not reach UI. With SQL scaling disabled all messages propagates to UI successfully.

Here is my Notification code:

```
public void OnNext(ResultModel value)
{
   Clients.Group(group).notify(value);
}
```

OnNext method always executes witho or without Scalling also *group* and *value* are correct. No exceptions thrown on UI or beckend. Below is UI part:

```
  var hubProxy = $.connection.visitsHub;

  hubProxy.client.notify = function (updatedResult) {
      console.log(updatedResult.Id);
    });
  };
```

Any help is appreciated.